# How to install and Play "Dota 2 OFFLINE" on Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, games

I can launch dota 2 from Steam, but I think it uses around [17GB since Source 2.](https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/6d7dzq/so_how_much_disk_space_takes_dota_now/) I want to Install [Dota 2 Offline version](http://www.tasikgame.com/2016/12/dota-2-offline-game-pc-free-download.html), the size are more smaller and faster download.

[image]